# How to get rid of blue borders around transparent objects in XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm a new XCode developer and as I've started up with some tutorials, I've noticed that as I design my layout, there is a strange blue border around objects that should appear transparent. They actually are transparent when you run the app, it has the borders, as shown in the pictures. I'm wondering if there is a way to get rid of these borders so the storyboard more accurately depicts what the app will look like.

In Storyboard:
[image: Storyboard]

In App:

[image: In App]

Thanks!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Perhaps you can uncheck Editor > Canvas > Show Bounds Rectangles of Xcode's menu.

[image]

Comment: There must be an hidden shortcut that enables that option. If you have a storyboard with 40+ view controllers with that option enabled XCode hangs even on the most powerful of MBP.

Comment: yep, i found this trap as well ;-) thank you for providing this solution!

Comment: For anyone coming to this recently like me. If unchecking doesn't work. uncheck, check, and then uncheck again to make it work.