# Story board showing all objects with rounded rectangles of blue borders

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, xib, xcode8

Story Board contain one class like Restaurent Details:

[image: Story Board contain one class like Restaurent Details]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rid of blue borders around transparent objects in XCode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813966/how-to-get-rid-of-blue-borders-around-transparent-objects-in-xcode)

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected behavior. Storyboard shows you the frames of the views and considering the auto-layout constrains. You can show/hide more information from the `Editor` menu.

```
Editor > canvas > show Bounds rectangles
```

Comment: In case it answered your question, you might want to accept it.